# Cardinality of the set of total functions from N to N

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have a question of :

> What is the cardinality of the set of total functions from N to N?

I guess the answer that is uncountable, and i need to prove it, How to start constructing  Cantor's diagonal argument to show that it can't be countable.

Comment: Like you said, use a diagonal argument. What are you stuck on?

Comment: @anomaly i am new in this field, i learned how to build it for real numbers, by taking the subset from 0 to 1, and build a contradiction. but it is not clear for me how to start the argument for Natural numbers, what subset should i select, what contradiction that i suppose to have here.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a diagonal argument the same way as you use it with real numbers. You suppose there exists a bijection between both sets and you find an element from the set of total functions from N to N that doesn't corresond with any natural number. Instead of changing the value of decimal positions as you do with real numbers, you have to change the image of natural numbers because you are working with functions.

Try seeing each function as an infinite vector (a1, ... , an, ...) where f(n) = an

Comment: what function should i select, should it be a function which will generate an images as not real number to show the contradiction ? or a function generate images of real numbers but not covering the the whole codomain so it is not a total function ?

Comment: No, you don't need to use real numbers for the proof, what I say is that you have to follow the same argument used for proving  $\mathbb R$ is uncountable. Do you know Cantor's diagonal argument and understand how it's used for $\mathbb R$? You said you used it with the interval (0, 1). Do the same just changing decimal positions by vector coordinates.

Comment: Ok i get it, i am just confused in the failing part of the argument between these 3 statements: (1) what you said "find an element from the set of total functions from N to N that doesn't corresond with any natural number' (2) or find a real number which is not counted there.(3)  or f fails to be onto because it misses {x∈S∣x∉f(S)} so it is not the assumed bijection. ? how to make the argument fail.

Comment: It's a mix between (1) and (3). You find an element (the element is a function) x∉f(N) so f cannot be a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For $\{f_n\in\omega^\omega:n\in\omega\}$ take $f:\omega\rightarrow\omega$ such that $f(n)\neq f_n(n)$.

Comment: why did you select $w^w$ ?

Comment: @RhastaShaman In set theory $\mathbb{N}$ is usually denoted by $\omega$.

Comment: what does it mean if we put it on the power of it self, why would we do that ? @Gödel

Comment: @RhastaShaman It is just notation. $\omega^\omega$ denotes the set of functions from $\omega$ to $\omega$.

Comment: thanks, how to make the argument fail according to your hint ? Gödel